# Angular - How to add a relative link to a word(s) that belongs to a text using a @Pipe decorator

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, binding

I am trying to create a 'Custom Pipe' that adds a **relative link** to a word(s) from dynamic inputs based on certain pattern (or variable in this case) that has the input.
**Example of input**: 'Miami is the capital of Florida.' (where 'Miami' is the variable value).
**Expected output**: 'Miami' redirects to whatever relative link for now (I use `routerLink`).

For now, I tried using `innerHTML` property but the word is not clickable.

I reproduced the situation in this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-link-pipes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhtml.pipes.ts

**UPDATE**

Using Directives instead of Pipes could be another option.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a pipe if this still stands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966635/angular-directives-vs-pipes

Comment: Thanks @JaqenH'ghar. It seems like a reasonable option. However, I don't have many experiencie with that. Can you please share any possible helpful resource?

Comment: Sorry if I am slow, but I can't see you can benefit anything. RouterLink is already a directive. You could also reuse a ng-template or create a component, but I don't think the syntax will be any simpler than Angular out of the box

Comment: if you only want a simple link it's possible of course: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319148/display-a-link-in-dynamically-obtained-html-text/62319557#62319557, but if you want to create a "component" on fly -really a `routerlink`is a directive, but it's the same- you can not. You can use an aproach like this another SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276306/dynamically-add-elements-to-the-editable-div-with-angular-and-anywhere/64277601#64277601